# How to get a report like page views, how long a user spends time for a specifice page on google analytics? Not a general report

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics

Right now, Google analytic gives a genereal page views for all users not a specific user. And User tracking gives history of user activities not how long they spend on a page, or total page views per user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to track **clientId** as custom dimension (users scope). This pseudonymously identifies a browser instance (i.e. `1260209636.1533332739`), it is the user in Google Analytics.

You can get this value with this function:

```
function() {
  try {
    var trackers = ga.getAll();
    var i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = trackers.length; i < len; i += 1) {
      if (trackers[i].get('trackingId') === "ID-PROPERTY") {
        return trackers[i].get('clientId');
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {}  
  return 'false';
}
```

where ID-PROPERTY is the id of your Property (i.e. UA-XXXXX-XX).

Then with a **custom report** you can use the *clientId* dimension with the various metrics and understand user by user how long they stay on the page, how many pages they visit, etc ...

Comment: You're welcome, upvote this answer is solved, pls :)